# Extract all form elements name htmlagilitypack

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms, html-agility-pack

i have this code to extract all form input element in html document. currently, i cant get select, textarea  and other elements except input element.

```
Dim htmldoc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlDocument()
        htmldoc.LoadHtml(txtHtml.Text)
        Dim root As HtmlNode = htmldoc.DocumentNode
        If root Is Nothing Then
            tsslStatus.Text = "Error parsing html"
        End If
        ' parse the page content
        For Each InputTag As HtmlNode In root.SelectNodes("//input")
            'get title
            Dim attName As String = Nothing
            Dim attType As String = Nothing
            For Each att As HtmlAttribute In InputTag.Attributes
                Select Case att.Name.ToLower
                    Case "name"
                        attName = att.Value
                    Case "type"
                        attType = att.Value
                End Select
                If attName Is Nothing OrElse attType Is Nothing Then
                    Continue For
                End If
                Dim sResult As String = String.Format("Type={0},Name={1}", attType, attName).ToLower

                If txtResult.Text.Contains(sResult) = False Then
                    'Debug.Print(sResult)
                    txtResult.Text &= sResult & vbCrLf
                End If

            Next
        Next
```

Can anyone help me on how to get all elements in all forms in the html document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution, what i did was use this

```
Dim Tags As HtmlNodeCollection = docNode.SelectNodes("//input | //select | //textarea")
```

thanks for looking